# R Updating database with dbi

Tags: r, sql-server, r-dbi

I have worked little bit with DBI in R and first question is more of best practice, as currently appending new data to DB is taking more time than I hoped. Second is error that I'm receiving when trying to update old information in database. Here is my current workflow when inserting new data to existing table in DB:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc(), "myDSN")

# Example table 1
tbl1 <- tibble(Key = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
               Val = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

# Original table in DB
dbWriteTable(con, "tbl1", tbl1, overwrite = TRUE)

# Link to Original table
db_tbl <- tbl(con, in_schema("dbo", "tbl1"))

# New data
tbl2 <- tibble(Key = c("D", "E", "F", "G", "H"),
               val = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14))

# Write it to Staging
dbWriteTable(con, "tbl1_staging", tbl2, overwrite = TRUE)

# Get a link to staging
db_tblStaging <- tbl(con, in_schema("dbo", "tbl1_staging"))

# Compare Info
not_in_db <- db_tblStaging %>% 
  anti_join(db_tbl, by="Key") %>% 
  collect()

# Append missing info to DB
dbWriteTable(con, "tbl1", not_in_db, append = TRUE)

# Voila!
dbReadTable(con, "tbl1")
```

That will do the trick, but I'm looking for better solution, as I hate the `collect()` part of the code, which means that I'm bringing something to in R memory (as far as I understand it) could be a problem in future, when I have bigger data. What I hoped would work is something like this, that would allow me to append new data to DB in a fly, without it visiting in memory.

```
# What I hoped to have
db_tblStaging %>% 
  anti_join(db_tbl, by="Key") %>% 
  dbWriteTable(con, "tbl1", ., append = TRUE)
```

Second problem is updating existing table. Here is what I tried, but error will emerge and can't figure it out. Here is link where I tried to copy the answer: [How to pass data.frame for UPDATE with R DBI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546468/how-to-pass-data-frame-for-update-with-r-dbi). I would like to update key E and D with new values in val.

```
# Trying to update tbl1
update_values <- db_tblStaging %>% 
  semi_join(db_tbl, by="Key") %>% 
  collect()

update <- dbSendQuery(con, 'UPDATE tbl1 
                            SET "val" = ? 
                            WHERE Key = ?')

dbBind(update, update_values)

Error in result_bind(res@ptr, as.list(params)) : 
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Key'.
```

Has the package changed in some way? I can't spot my syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider running pure SQL after your table staging uploads as it looks like you need the `NOT EXISTS` (to avoid duplicates) and `UPDATE INNER JOIN` (for existing records). This avoids any R client side query imports and exports.

And [*Key*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql) is a reserved word in SQL Server. Hence, escape it with square brackets.

```
apn_sql <- "INSERT INTO dbo.tbl (s.[Key], s.[Val])
            SELECT s.[Key], s.[Val] FROM dbo.tbl_staging s
            WHERE NOT EXISTS
              (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.tbl t
               WHERE t.[Key] = s.[Key])"

dbSendQuery(con, apn_sql)

upd_sql <- "UPDATE t
            SET t.Val = s.Val
            FROM dbo.tbl t 
            INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_staging s 
               ON t.[Key] = s.[Key]"

dbSendQuery(con, upd_sql)
```

[Rextester demo](http://rextester.com/HYFBM59155)

In fact, SQL Server has the [`MERGE`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx) query to handle both in one call:

```sql
MERGE dbo.tbl AS Target
USING (SELECT [Key], [Val] FROM dbo.tbl_staging) AS Source
  ON (Target.[Key] = Source.[Key])
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Target.Val = Source.Val
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT ([Key], [Val])
    VALUES (Source.[Key], Source.[Val]);
```

[Rextester demo](http://rextester.com/RJNM6426)